wrapAll not triggering on a paginated page
I hade some help recently to get two  tags wrapped in a div. This works great on page load but these pages are a paginated WordPress/WooCommrece page and when navigating the wrap isn't working.
Current code:
$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.link-b,.link-c').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
});

.wrapped {
  background: grey;
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link b</a>
  <a class="link-c">link c</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link b</a>
  <a class="link-c">link c</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link b</a>
  <a class="link-c">link c</a>
</div>

So on load / refresh work fine.
Is there a way to re-run the wrapAll script each time the pagination is triggered? Or perhaps there is a better solution? You can see the issue here: londonglamourgarden.com.fsd-dev.co.uk/shop
